# Плавное увеличение нижнего подчеркивания у текста

Tags: css

Есть нижняя граница у текста, как сделать её плавное увеличение при наведении из центра слова до его краёв?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так должно быть, в конечном результате.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не понятно что конкретно вы имеете в виду в фразе _«граница будет плавно увеличиваться до границ.»_ Ширина подчеркивания будет увеличиваться из центра, или что? Постарайтесь объяснить подробнее, а то вон уже минусы ставят

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да, ширина подчёркивания будет увеличиваться из центра слова до его границ(как сейчас на картинке).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используем псевдо-элемент и сжимаем-разжимаем его по ширине при наведении:

Через `transform`:

```css
.link{
   text-decoration:none;
   position:relative;
}

.link:before{
   position:absolute;
   bottom: -10px;
   content: " ";
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   transform: scale(0,1);
   width:100%;
   transition: transform 0.3s
}

.link:hover:before{
   transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

```html
<a class='link' href='#'>Ссылка</a>
```

Через `width`:

```css
.link{
   text-decoration:none;
   position:relative;
}

.link:before{
   position:absolute;
   bottom: -10px;
   content: " ";
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   left:50%;
   width:0%;
   transition: all 0.3s;
}

.link:hover:before{
   width:100%;
   left:0%
}
```

```html
<a class='link' href='#'>Ссылка</a>
```