# Расширить нижнюю границу при наведении

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-animation

Я пытаюсь получить эффект `transition` расширения подчеркивания слева или справа до конца при наведении

```css
h1 {
  color: #666;
}

h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  width: 275px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out, right 250ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

h1:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
```

Моя попытка: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfn5nefb/)

Перевод вопроса: [Expand bottom border on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623446/expand-bottom-border-on-hover/28623513#28623513)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Плавное увеличение нижнего подчеркивания у текста](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631757/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @Crantisz на мой взгляд, здесь более полное решение, с большим количеством вариантов.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623446/expand-bottom-border-on-hover/28623513#28623513

Comment: @Crantisz добавлю ещё уточнение -,  это перевод оригинальной статьи с enSO, которая была опубликована  ровно на два года раньше вашей статьи - answered Feb 20 '15 at 7:16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы расширить нижнюю границу при наведении, вы можете использовать `transform: scaleX '();` ([ссылка mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)) и переход от 0 к 1 в состоянии `hover`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Граница и `transition` устанавливаются на псевдоэлементе, чтобы предотвратить переход текста и избежать добавления разметки.
Чтобы развернуть нижнюю границу слева или справа, вы можете изменить свойство `transform-origin` слева или справа от псевдоэлемента:

```css
h1 { color: #666;display:inline-block; margin:0;text-transform:uppercase; }
h1:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
h1:hover:after { transform: scaleX(1); }
h1.fromRight:after{ transform-origin:100% 50%; }
h1.fromLeft:after{  transform-origin:  0% 50%; }
```

```html
<h1 class="fromCenter">Expand from center</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromRight">Expand from right</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromLeft">Expand from left</h1>
```

### Развернуть нижнюю границу при наведении двумя линиями

Вы можете достичь того же эффекта, когда текст занимает 2 строки. Псевдоэлемент `before` абсолютно позиционирован, чтобы подчеркнуть первую строку устанавливается - `bottom: 1.2em;`:

```css
h1 { position:relative;color: #666;display:inline-block; margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;line-height:1.2em; }
h1:after, h1:before {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
h1:before{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:1.2em; left:0;
  width:100%;
}
.ef2:hover:after {
  transition-delay:150ms;
}
  
h1:hover:after, h1:hover:before { transform: scaleX(1); }
```

```html
<h1>Expand border<br/>on two lines</h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<h1 class="ef2">Expand border<br/>effect two</h1>
```

### Различное направление подчеркивания при наведении и отведении курсора:

```css
h1 { color: #666;display:inline-block; margin:0;text-transform:uppercase; }
h1:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
h1.fromLeft:after{ transform-origin: 100% 50%; }
h1.fromRight:after{  transform-origin:   0% 50%; }
h1:hover:after { transform: scaleX(1); }
h1.fromLeft:hover:after{ transform-origin:   0% 50%; }
h1.fromRight:hover:after{  transform-origin: 100% 50%; }
```

```html
<h1 class="fromRight">Expand from right</h1><br/>
<h1 class="fromLeft">Expand from left</h1>
```

Перевод ответа: [Expand bottom border on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623446/expand-bottom-border-on-hover/28623513#28623513) @web-tiki