# Динмаическая полоска под пунктом меню при наведении?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Подскажите как реализовать динамическую полоску под пунктом меню при наведении? 
Чтобы полоска плавно появлялась из центра и уходила в обе стороны на 100% ширины.
prnt.sc/em45xc как на картинке примерно.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Плавное увеличение нижнего подчеркивания у текста](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631757/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так делает , через псевдо элемент

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

li:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

li:hover {
  transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
  color: #111;
}

li:last-child ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000%;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(3);
}

li:last-child:hover ul {
  top: 100%;
  transition: top .4s ease-in-out, transform .4s linear;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li>Главная</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Гостевая</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Сайты</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Портфолио</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>О нас</li>
  <!--
  -->
  <li>Проекты
    <ul>
      <li>Проект 1</li>
      <li>Проект 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</menu>
```