# Анимированный бордер на css или js?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

Когда верстал сайт ставил нижние границы на серый цвет и переход на 0.3s,при наведении (hover) менял границы на синий цвет. Дело в том что при наведении, анимация нижней-границы(синего цвета), появляется сверху вниз(то есть 'падает').
[image: Меню]

Сейчас клиент хочет, что бы граница появлялась слева направо, и что бы при наведении курсором на второй элемент списка, граница первого не пропадала, а как бы "догоняла"  курсор и заполняла границу второго. Надеюсь смог понятно объяснить. Так вот в чем вопрос как я знаю это на css невозможно сделать,а на js я не знаю как,можете помочь что и как надо изменить, без jQuery или доп.фреймворков .

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Плавное увеличение нижнего подчеркивания у текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631757/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: нет,здесь только решение одной проблемы,и то полное

Comment: Самое простое - создать дополнительный блок с абсолютным позиционированием в основном меню с синем бордюром снизу. При наведении на элемент меню, при помощи JQuery (я вижу решение только с ним) анимируете свойство "left" у элемента с абсолютным позиционированием до наведенного блока (если конкретно - left = $(menuHoverItem).position().left). При необходимости можно сделать возвращение блока обратно на выбранную страницу в меню,  если пользователь убрал курсор. Если Вас устроит этот вариант, то могу помочь с его реализацией